# SQL - Obtain word between two word in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table (house_1) with field term_list with this structure...

[id-537,typeOfObject-'house',workNumber-631,title-'A beautifull House',titleGerman-'Eine schöne Haus',titleEnglish-'A beautifull House',titleFrench-'Une maison magnifique',
finishedPlace-'Traun',year-1966,heightMm-480,widthMm-665]

I tried with this, but don't return anything...

```
SELECT * 
FROM house_1 
WHERE term_list LIKE '%titleEnglish-\'% beautifull %\',title%'"
```

I know the db design is disgusting, but is impossible redesign in this moment.

Any idea? Very Thanks...

Comment: I realise you probably have no control over the database, but this is a great example of how not to design a database.

Comment: Problem may lie elsewhere because that `LIKE` seems to work when I tested it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM `house_1` WHERE `term_list` REGEXP "^(.)*(titleEnglish){1}(.)*(beautifull){1}(.)*$"
```

Please note that it is a slow query.